# Why is my watch not triggered in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

In my directive I have this watch:

```
scope.$watch(function () { return $(".submenu").is(":visible"); }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
    scope.vm.isHorizontalMenuVisible = newVal;
});
```

What I want is simple: set `scope.vm.isHorizontalMenuVisible` to true when a div with the class `submenu` is visible, e.g. `display: block`. But my watch is only triggered when the page loads and then never again. I am 100% sure that the specific div is visible, because when I enter `$(".submenu").is(":visible")` in my log, it returns, depending whether the div is visible, true or false.

Could someone explain to me why this isn't working and how to fix this?

I am using Angular 1.3

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Your JavaScript code should not mess with the DOM. The whole point of angularJS is to make the **model** the single point of truth, and to have the view updated based on what the **model** contains. Watch changes in the model, not on the view.

Comment: I can't do that. In my css when an element is hovered, I make a div visible and when this happens I want to that.

Comment: If the visibility of the div is entirely controlled by pure CSS, that happens outside of angular: there is no JavaScript event that would cause angular to start a new digest cycle and reevaluate the watched expressions. Use ng-mouse-xxx events.

Comment: If it's a hover event that causes a CSS change you can add a hover event on that same item to trigger something in Angular. Can you post your whole directive? Typically you would see something like `<div ng-mouseenter="doSomething(true)" ng-mouseleave="doSomething(false)">`

Comment: @JBNizet Makes sense, thanks :)
@azium I now indeed use a `data-ng-mouseover`